# UseLazyLoadingProxies with EF core loads whole list when adding a new child entity

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

I'm using UseLazyLoadingProxies with EF core, postgresql and DDD architecture. I have Parent and Child objects lets say they look something like this:

```
public class Parent 
{
    public int Id { get; private set;}
    public string Name {get; private set}
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children {get; private set}

    public void AddChild(Child child)
    {
        Children.Add(child);
    }
}

public class Child 
{
    public int Id { get; private set;}
    public string Name {get; private set}
}
```

when I use `parent.Add(child)` proxy does its thing and pulls whole list of child elements before adding new child in the list, is there a way to work around it? because child elements can be 50 000 and right now its pulling all the rows from database for no reason other than to add a new child entity

Answer (score 1):

Although lazy loading should be avoided at all costs, not only because of issues such as you describe here, there is a way to prevent addressing the collection property: use a [backing field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field):

```
public class Parent 
{
    List<Child> _children = new List<Child>();

    public int Id { get; private set;}
    public string Name {get; private set}

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children
    {
        get => _children;
        private set => _children = value;
    }

    public void AddChild(Child child)
    {
        _children.Add(child);
    }
}
```

Since the backing field `_children` follows the naming conventions for backing field discovery, no additional configuration is needed.

If there's no method to set `_children`, the private setter can even be removed entirely and the field be made `readonly`.